# Loop seemingly blocking on attempting to write a minimal Behaviour system like Unity's

Tags: c#

I tried to write an API that would allow the creation of Behaviours in the manner of Unity. This is just a little experiment to learn about this language, I am also new to programming in general.

The test class I made is supposed to write indefinitely to the console what you specified in the constructor, but there is no output. The loop seems to be blocked.
Here is what I wrote:

1 - Program.cs

```
using System.IO;

namespace Program {
    
    public abstract class Script {
        public abstract void Start();
        public abstract void Update();
    }
    
    class Program {
        
        static bool IsKeyDown(ConsoleKey key) {
            if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == key) return true;
            else return false;
        }
        
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            Script[] scriptList = {
                new Write("Hello World"),
            };
            foreach (Script s in scriptList) {
                s.Start();
            }
            while (!IsKeyDown(ConsoleKey.Escape)) {
                foreach (Script s in scriptList) {
                    s.Update();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2 - Write.cs

```
using System;

namespace Program {

    public class Write : Script {
        string str;
        public Write(string _str) {
            str = _str;
        }
        public override void Start(){}
        public override void Update(){
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code blocks on the [Console.ReadKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_ReadKey). If there are no keys available in the input buffer then ReadKey stops and waits for the user to press a key.
You can read this info in the docs where they say

> One of the most common uses of the ReadKey() method is to halt program
>   execution until the user presses a key and the app either terminates
>   or displays an additional window of information.

You just need to add

```
static bool IsKeyDown(ConsoleKey key)
{
    if (!Console.KeyAvailable) return false;
    if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == key) return true;
    else return false;
}
```